# Is there a way to use Low Search to return results by author?

Tags: search, low-search, author

We would like to be able to perform a free text search using an author name and return all posts credited to that author, is this possible with Low Search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method Jamie mentioned will indeed work. You can also try and use [Low Author](https://github.com/low/low_author), which saves the author screen name as a searchable read-only field. Add that field to your entries, and you'll be able to use keywords to search by author.

**Edit:** If you're using Low Search 4+, you can now also use [the Members filter](https://github.com/low/low_search_members). Once installed, use the parameters `members:screen_name` (exact matches) or `members:search:screen_name` (partial matches) with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if anything has changed in more recent versions, but Low himself suggested using Solspace's Preparse addon for cases like this:

http://gotolow.com/blog/searching-non-field-data-with-low-search